# How to solve multipart resolver in spring?? java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItemFactory

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven, multipartform-data

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.ssts</groupId>
    <artifactId>momcab1</artifactId>
    <name>momcab1</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.7</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>4.0.3.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.7.4</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.7.5</org.slf4j-version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.5.Final</hibernate.version>
        <mysql.version>5.1.32</mysql.version>
        <spring.security.version>3.2.5.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
        <spring.batch.version>2.2.0.RELEASE</spring.batch.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
    <!--spring and hibernate validation -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Commons DBCP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Commons FileUpload -->
         <dependency>
   <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.1</version> 
</dependency>


        <!-- Spring ORM -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>   

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>${mysql.version}</version>
</dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
<!--  Java Mail Dependency -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
    <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>


<!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security JSP Taglib -->
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
<!-- Spring new dependencies for Batch start-->
<!-- Spring Core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Batch dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.batch.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-infrastructure</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.batch.version}</version>
        </dependency>
<!-- Spring new dependencies for Batch end-->

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

momcab-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
        ">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ssts.momcab.controller" />
    <!-- configuring the location of properties file -->
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:Application.properties" />
    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
    <beans:property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000"/>
</beans:bean> 
     <!-- Here Defining required DB connectivity properties -->
    <beans:bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
        <beans:property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="${database.username}" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
    <beans:bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>com.ssts.momcab.model.Admin</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.ssts.momcab.model.Register</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.ssts.momcab.model.User</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.ssts.momcab.model.Booking</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.ssts.momcab.model.Chaffeur</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.ssts.momcab.model.Child</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.ssts.momcab.model.Driver</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.ssts.momcab.model.CustTransaction</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.ssts.momcab.model.ServiceRequest</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.ssts.momcab.model.Offer</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.ssts.momcab.model.MsgNotification</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.ssts.momcab.model.CustFeedback</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.ssts.momcab.model.BizLocation</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.ssts.momcab.model.LoggedinUser</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.ssts.momcab.model.UserBizLocMap</beans:value>
            </beans:list>

        </beans:property>
        <!-- Here defining  Hibernate required properties -->
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}
                </beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}
                </beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="adminDAO" class="com.ssts.momcab.dao.AdminDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
            ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="registerDAO" class="com.ssts.momcab.dao.RegisterDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
            ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="userDAO" class="com.ssts.momcab.dao.UserDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
            ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="adminService" class="com.ssts.momcab.service.AdminServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="adminDAO" ref="adminDAO"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="registerService" class="com.ssts.momcab.service.RegisterServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="registerDAO" ref="registerDAO"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="userService" class="com.ssts.momcab.service.UserServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="userDAO" ref="userDAO"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="bookingDAO" class="com.ssts.momcab.dao.BookingDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
            ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="bookingService" class="com.ssts.momcab.service.BookingServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="bookingDAO" ref="bookingDAO"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="chaffeurDAO" class="com.ssts.momcab.dao.ChaffeurDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
            ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="chaffeurService" class="com.ssts.momcab.service.ChaffeurServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="chaffeurDAO" ref="chaffeurDAO"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="childDAO" class="com.ssts.momcab.dao.ChildDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
            ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="childService" class="com.ssts.momcab.service.ChildServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="childDAO" ref="childDAO"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="driverDAO" class="com.ssts.momcab.dao.DriverDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
            ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="driverService" class="com.ssts.momcab.service.DriverServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="driverDAO" ref="driverDAO"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="serviceRequestDAO" class="com.ssts.momcab.dao.ServiceRequestDaoImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
            ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="serviceRequestService"
        class="com.ssts.momcab.service.ServiceRequestServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="serviceRequestDAO" ref="serviceRequestDAO"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="custTransactionDAO" class="com.ssts.momcab.dao.CustTransactionDaoImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
            ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="custTransactionService"
        class="com.ssts.momcab.service.CustTransactionServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="custTransactionDAO" ref="custTransactionDAO"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="offerDAO" class="com.ssts.momcab.dao.OfferDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
            ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="offerService" class="com.ssts.momcab.service.OfferServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="offerDAO" ref="offerDAO"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="msgNotificationDAO" class="com.ssts.momcab.dao.MsgNotificationDaoImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
            ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="msgNotificationService"
        class="com.ssts.momcab.service.MsgNotificationServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="msgNotificationDAO" ref="msgNotificationDAO" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="custFeedbackDAO" class="com.ssts.momcab.dao.CustFeedbackDaoImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
            ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="custFeedbackService"
        class="com.ssts.momcab.service.CustFeedbackServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="custFeedbackDAO" ref="custFeedbackDAO"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="bizLocationDAO" class="com.ssts.momcab.dao.BizLocationDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
            ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="bizLocationService"
        class="com.ssts.momcab.service.BizLocationServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="bizLocationDAO" ref="bizLocationDAO" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="loggedinUserDAO" class="com.ssts.momcab.dao.LoggedinUserDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
            ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="loggedinUserService"
        class="com.ssts.momcab.service.LoggedinUserServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="loggedinUserDAO" ref="loggedinUserDAO" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="userBizLocMapDAO" class="com.ssts.momcab.dao.UserBizLocMapDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
            ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="userBizLocMapService"
        class="com.ssts.momcab.service.UserBizLocMapServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="userBizLocMapDAO" ref="userBizLocMapDAO" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="pgService1" class="com.ssts.momcab.service.PGService1Impl">
    </beans:bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <beans:bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
            ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

Driver.jsp

```
 <c:url var="addAction" value="/Drivers/add"></c:url>

                <form:form action="${addAction}" enctype="multipart/form-data" commandName="driver">
                    <table width="400px" height="150px">

                        <tr>
                            <td><form:label path="name">
                                    <spring:message text="Driver Name" />
                                </form:label></td>
                            <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td><form:label path="license">
                                    <spring:message text="License Number" />
                                </form:label></td>
                            <td><form:input path="license" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><form:label path="password">
                                    <spring:message text="Password" />
                                </form:label></td>
                            <td><form:input type="password" path="password" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><form:label path="address">
                                    <spring:message text="Address" />
                                </form:label></td>
                            <td><form:input path="address" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><form:label path="number">
                                    <spring:message text="Mobile Number" />
                                </form:label></td>
                            <td><form:input path="number" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><form:label path="blobImg">
                                    <spring:message text="File" />
                                </form:label></td>
                            <td><form:input type="file" path="blobImg" /></td>
                        </tr>


                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="submit" value="<spring:message text="Submit"/>" /></td>
                            </tr>
                    </table>
                </form:form>
```

DriverController.java

```
package com.ssts.momcab.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;







import com.ssts.momcab.model.Admin;
import com.ssts.momcab.model.Driver;
import com.ssts.momcab.service.BookingService;
import com.ssts.momcab.service.DriverService;
import com.ssts.momcab.util.MomcabUtil;

import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile;

@Controller
public class DriverController {

    @Value("${login_session_token_timeout_mnts}")
    private String loginSessionTokenTimeoutMnts;

    private DriverService driverService;

    @Autowired(required = true)
    @Qualifier(value = "driverService")
    public void setDriverService(DriverService ds) {
        this.driverService = ds;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/Drivers", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String Drivers(Model model,HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res) {

        HttpSession session =req.getSession();
         if(session.getAttribute("emailId")==null)
         {
             return "redirect:/login";
         }
        model.addAttribute("driver", new Driver());

        return "driver";
    }



    @RequestMapping(value = "/Drivers/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String Driver(@ModelAttribute("driver") Driver driver,@RequestParam("blobImg") MultipartFile blobImg) throws IOException {

        if (driver.getId() == 0) {
            // new user, add to DB



                if (blobImg != null && !blobImg.isEmpty())
                {
                    byte[] bytes = blobImg.getBytes();
                    driver.setBlobImg(bytes);
                }               




            }
            this.driverService.addDriver(driver);





    return "redirect:/Drivers";
}
}
```

So when i am giving an image and clicking on submit then i am getting an error like this[image]

Even i added "commons-logging" in pom.xml
and "bean" of "multipartResolver" in momcab-servlet.xml its not even running in my tomcat. so idk where my error is occuring.Any help in this is appreciated.
Thanking you

Comment: Why should adding `commons-logging` help? You are missing the `commons-fileupload` dependency.

Comment: @M.Deinum If you scroll the "pom.xml" file i posted you can see i added a dependancy "commons-logging-1.2.1"

Comment: Well the problem here is when i add "commons-logging" dependancy in pom.xml and run the server i am not getting any error. But when i add "bean" in dispatcher-servlet.xml and run the server then i am getting the error

Comment: Your stack trace is complaining about a missing class from `commons-fileupload` **not** from `commons-logging`. Also instead of posting stack traces as images post them as code so that they are readable and scrollable (the interesting part of the stack trace is actually missing). You have a `commons-fileupload` dependency of 1.2.2 which is ancient (2010) use the newer 1.3.2 version at least.

Comment: The stacktrace should be a text, not a picture. We trust you that there is an exception, so it would be better to have the text instead of the picture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i solved my problem. i just added `commons-fileupload` but i didn't add `commons-io` so i added them and my problem is solved

```
<!-- Apache Commons FileUpload --> 
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Apache Commons IO --> 
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
```